# Mockito and Spring autowired

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have problem while writing test for `getStudentInfo()`, I want to make a real call to `getaddress()` instead of using `expects`.

```
public class Student {
    @Autowired
    private Address address;

    public String getStudentInfo(String name) {
        string address = address.getAddress(name);
        return address;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class StudentTest {
    @InjectMock
    private Student student;

    @Test
    public void testStudentInfo() {
        String name = student.getStudentInfo("name");
    }
}
```

When use above approach, Address object is not creating. I don't want to use the `new` keyword to create new Address object.

Comment: Write a protected constructor `protected Student(final Address address)` and inject a spy of type `Address` through this constructor. If you use `Spring`, it is general recommended to inject dependencies through constructor parameters.

Comment: Data objects should never use autowiring. `Address` should use a normal setter and/or constructor setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is wrong to have `@Autowire` there. Just add a constructor or setter method.

After that, you need to [mock (spy)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) that stuff. Try this:

```
public class StudentTest {
    @InjectMock
    private Student student;

    // this mock will be injected into student
    // but the real method will be called (unless a method was stubbed explicitly).
    @Spy
    private Address address;

    @Test
    public void testStudentInfo(){
        String name = student.getStudentInfo("name");
    }
}
```

The stuff you need in general is called partial mock. See the link at the top.

Comment: Better to use `@Mock` and mock the `Student` method calls.

Comment: @daniu but the author wants to call a real method for some reason )

Comment: is it possible to make both real and mock call in same class but different method?

Comment: @user2514421 yes, that is exactly what `@Spy` is used for. when you 'spy' object - real methods are called, if you want to stub some method just do for that particular method something like `when(spyObject.someMethod()).thenReturn(100);` and only that one will be stubbed, for all the rest real stuff will be invoked.

Comment: using spy i can only able create object for address in student class, suppose in address class if u have an autowired component, can we are create object for that component too?